# Why is my lead acid battery suddenly dead?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, battery-operated, lead-acid, battery-chemistry

I have a 12v 12ah sealed lead acid battery that was used 3 years in a battery friendly environment. Now I wanted to use it to power a security camera.

I use a cv cc buck converter as a charger. I charge the battery at 13,6v and 1a because it says that on the battery. I designed a 11,5v cutoff circuit to not deep discharge the battery when in use. The camera draws 150ma.

Now the first use cycle everything went fine. I charged it to 13,6v until the current flow stopped then it discharged to 11,5v in the calculated time.

In the second use cycle it only lasted half the usual time and when I connect it to the charger the voltage jumps up to 13,6v instantly.

My questions are:

Is the battery broken?

If yes why did it break so suddenly after working fine for so long?

If no why does it behave like that?

Comment: Used 3 years? Perhaps it was just at end-of-life.  Try with a new battery of the same brand and model.

Comment: SLA batteries only last around 3 years. Sometimes you might get 5 years if you’re lucky. The deep discharge cutoff voltage depends on the discharge rate. For light loads it is a higher goltage, for heavy loads, lower voltage. The actual voltage depends on the size of battery and the discharge rate. Refer to the battery datasheet as most manufacturers with give you graphs to determine actual cuttoff voltage. One size does not fit alll!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You overdischarged it, and probably it's old besides.

As lead-acid discharges, on the one electrode, lead sulfate builds up -- an insulator.  This is why internal resistance increases as the battery discharges: less electrode area is available for reaction.  Initially, the layer is thin and amorphous, and easily decomposed on charging -- reversible.  With increasing discharge, and as more time is spent before charging, the layer grows in thickness, and begins to crystallize.  Crystals are not decomposed on charging -- irreversible, and this is one mechanism of capacity loss.

A fully discharged battery will have low terminal voltage (under 11.6V), very high resistance (a modest load may bring the voltage all the way to zero), and likewise charges very slowly.

On charging from such a state, the resistance gradually decreases as the small initial current flows.  Over time, the voltage drops as the battery is able to accept full charging current.  Eventually, it returns to a normal cycle state, albeit at reduced capacity.

You will probably find the next such cycle only has perhaps 80% of rated capacity.  And so on, less and less with repeated deep cycling.  The recovery rate isn't even all that great for "deep cycle" types.  Lead acid is best used for shallow discharges, while maintained near full charge -- think car batteries and uninterruptible power supplies, where use is most likely closely followed by a charge cycle.

As for age, the materials are constantly in flux -- at equilibrium when no current flows, but exchange is always happening.  Lead sulfate crystals grow, lead dioxide decomposes, the lead metal itself recrystallizes and shifts over time.  Electrolyte also evaporates (water loss, raising the concentration of sulfuric acid), or is lost due to electrolysis (overcharging).  Eventually, electrodes and connections begin to crumble, surface area is blocked by sulfation, cells become unbalanced due to internal leakage (including by shorting due to crumbling electrodes or dendrite formation), or electrolyte loss, etc.  This marks end-of-life, as available charge drops off sharply, self-discharge becomes unacceptable, or whole cells go short or open.

Comment: Do you think I should use a different battery type for continuous discharge and charge cycles?

Comment: @Panthera It's fine for this kind of application, just don't discharge it so far, or get a bigger one (or a few more in parallel) to the same end.

Comment: Okay thank you very much for your help